# Load other function with method POST in jQuery

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-post

In the console print "aaa", but I can not make it print "bbb" by clicking on click $("#test").

That mistake I'm making? Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.
Sorry for my bad English.

**main.js:**

```
$("#load").click(function () {
    $.post("second.php",function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

**main.html:**

```
...
<div id="result"></div>
...
```

**second.php return:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        try
        {
            console.log("aaa");
            $("#test").click(function () {
                console.log("bbb");
                return false;
            });
        }catch(e){}
    });
</script>

<div>hello</div>
<a id="test" href="#">Test</a>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? I think you misunderstand how POST works.

Comment: I'm trying to load a page from php, I just put the code as simple as possible. The loaded page has its own functions js.

Comment: ahh, nvm I thought second.php was a HTML page. do console.log(data); and see what you get.

Comment: I know, but I need to be POST, he sent a form, but the problem is that I do not recognize the functions that are loaded into the answer.

Comment: why are you placing a click handler in a `try/catch` block?

Comment: I do not think that is the reason of the problem. Because "aaa" is printed on the console. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `document.ready` has already occured in the main page. This means that any code in your AJAX will fire immediately even when wrapped in `document.ready`. If the code precedes the html it referrs to, it will fire before the html exists

If you place your code after the same html it will work.

The alternative is to use `on()` to delegate event handlers to future elements that don't exist when page loads. Uou can use `on()` in the main page and run it when main page loads

Delegation example

```
$(document).on('click','#test', function(){

   console.log('bbbb');
   return false;
});
```

Comment: not sure which version...you don't want to load code with `on()` for same element numerous times...will add a new handler each time. Bascally switching order html and js is simplest fix for you

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Now I keep looking for information on the comments.